# Are there any DSL's for filtering collections in JS?

Tags: javascript, collections, dsl

I'm looking for available extenstions over filtering collections in JS. Ideally would be that js would understand some SQL-like syntax so that I could transfer part of ORM-made queries into js client.

Why do I need it:

Suppose, I have SPA(Single Page Application) and server layer. I have a scenario when user is allowed to customize appearance, validations and filters used in SPA web application. This customization is made in DESKTOP(!) application (metaInfo app) and MUST be used by server(for retrieving data) and SPA (apperance, client validations).

That metaInfo app and server share one common ORM and that ORM also has a set of specific desktop-only UI controls aiming to help user input filters in user friendly style. So server and metainfo app coup together quite well. SPA doesn't know anything about it.

Now I need to transfer part of that user customizations into SPA. My idea is to preview ORM queries and send is to SPA. The problem is how to teach js to filter collections in sql-like syntax. Otherwise I would need to translate sql queries into js callback functions for filtering which is a complex task.